# DNS 3rd level domains

Tags: dns, web, hosting, plesk

i got 1 domain www.name1.it and a 3rdlevel shop.name1.it both with manual DNS settings.

i also got a dedicated server with plesk where there is 2 hosting www.bsoul.it and shop.bsoul.it (subfolder of second level domain)

the second level domain is pointing that server ip with the www record

my quetion is: how do i point the shop.name1.it DNS to that same sever?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear as you mention you have already manually set DNS. You need to add the A record to bsoul.it:

```
Host          TTL          Type          IP
shop          14400        A             100.100.100.100
```

This will point shop.bsoul.it to you server if you enter the correct IP.